# Prevent inferred zod types from being anonymous

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the following zod definitions

```
const Point = z.object({
    x: z.number(),
    y: z.number(),
});

type Point = z.infer<typeof Point>;
```

Now if I use this inferred type somewhere, e.g.

```
const p: Point = {x: 1, y: 3};
```

then when I hover my mouse over the variable `p` in VSCode, I get a tooltip that says

```
const p: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

instead of

```
const p: Point
```

Now you might say that this is a minor issue, but imagine in a real life application that you have a function defined as

```
function callApi(<some args>): Promise<ApiResponse>
```

where `ApiResponse` is a large inferred type and use it like this:

```
const resp = await callApi(...);
```

I think it would be really nice (i.e. it would be good DX) if hovering your mouse over the `resp` variable, you got `const resp: ApiResponse` in the tooltip instead of a huge `{...}` with a gazillion lines in it. This way, you would know that `callApi` returns a `ApiResponse` without having to look at the definition of the function.

Is there a solution to this problem? One workaround that I tried is to do

```
interface Point extends z.infer<typeof Point> {}
```

instead of `type Point = z.infer<typeof Point>;`, but this only works for plain object types, it won't work with e.g. (discriminated) unions.

Comment: Well, you actually DO get `ApiResponse` in the tooltip if it's large enough. It's an editor problem, not TypeScript. Your editor just seems to like showing the whole type if it's small enough. These kinds of things are determined by heuristics - things that are the way they are because analysis shows that this would be the *most optimal* for the *most people*.

Comment: That has not been my experience with VSCode. If the type is defined explicitly, i.e. with `type ApiResponse = {...}` or `interface ApiResponse {...}`, it always shows the type name, regardless of the size of the type. If the type is inferred by zod, it always shows the type structure, regardless of the size of the type.